# How to check for each column if row is empty?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I created an simple program that retrieves data from a .txt file. A small part of the .txt file:

[image: screenshot]

The 4 digit number between the ( and )  and the hexadecimal between < and > is the data, I am referring to.
After I sliced it, I want to write the data into an excel file.

I wrote (an ugly) code that will remember the row number and write the data into a cell below for each column (9 columns in total)

Is there a better way to get the same result? I would like to improve.

```
import openpyxl

infile = open('test.txt')

s = infile.readlines()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Main.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
VariableRow1 = 2
VariableRow2 = 2
VariableRow3 = 2
VariableRow4 = 2
VariableRow5 = 2
VariableRow6 = 2
VariableRow7 = 2
VariableRow8 = 2
VariableRow9 = 2
for i in range(len(s)):
    if '<' in s[i] and '(' in s[i]:

        PijlOpen = s[i].find('<')
        PijlDicht = s[i].find('>')
        HaakjeOpen = s[i].find('(')
        HaakjeDicht = s[i].find(')')
        Number = (s[i])[HaakjeOpen + 1:HaakjeDicht]
        Number = Number.replace('0', '')

        Value = (s[i])[PijlOpen + 1:PijlDicht]

        Value = Value.replace(' ', '')
        Value = bytes.fromhex(Value).decode('utf-8')
        Number = int(Number)
        
        if Number == 1:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow1, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow1 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow1, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        if Number == 2:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow2, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow2 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow2, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        if Number == 3:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow3, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow3 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow3, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
            
        if Number == 4:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow4, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow4 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow4, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        if Number == 5:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow5, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow5 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow5, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        if Number == 6:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow6, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow6 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow6, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
            
        if Number == 7:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow7, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow7 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow7, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        if Number == 8:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow8, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow8 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow8, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        if Number == 9:
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow9, column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow9 += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow9, column=Number)
            cell.value = Value

        wb.save(filename='Main.xlsx')
print ('Finished')
```

Comment: In general, if you are using more than 3-4 if statements in a loop, it's often a good idea switch to using a list to define the if statements within the loop.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? How could I use a list to define the if statements?

Comment: @Mike67's answer below has done just this. The idea is that if you have a list of variables you can use the index of that list to store that data. We know which index of the list we want so don't have to check if it is the right one across all the variables with if statements now!

Comment: Woooh that's super clever! Thank you both so much, now I understand it :D

Comment: In general, using a regex for processing logfiles is the way to go. Once you've worked out the regex, and that can take a while!, the rest of the code can be a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can be reduced by using a list instead of the 9 variables:

Try this code:

```
import openpyxl

infile = open('test.txt')

s = infile.readlines()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='Main.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
VariableRow = [2]*9  # index 0-8

for i in range(len(s)):
    if '<' in s[i] and '(' in s[i]:

        PijlOpen = s[i].find('<')
        PijlDicht = s[i].find('>')
        HaakjeOpen = s[i].find('(')
        HaakjeDicht = s[i].find(')')
        Number = (s[i])[HaakjeOpen + 1:HaakjeDicht]
        Number = Number.replace('0', '')

        Value = (s[i])[PijlOpen + 1:PijlDicht]

        Value = Value.replace(' ', '')
        Value = bytes.fromhex(Value).decode('utf-8')
        Number = int(Number)
        
        if number in range(1,10):  # 1-9
            if ws.cell(row=VariableRow[number-1], column=Number).value != None:
                VariableRow[number-1] += 1
            cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow[number-1], column=Number)
            cell.value = Value
        
        wb.save(filename='Main.xlsx')
print ('Finished')
```

Comment: The variableRow1 isn't correct or am I missing something?

cell = ws.cell(row=VariableRow1, column = Number)